# tool/utility too analyze and solve css modern browser quirks and pecularities?

Tags: css, css-transitions, compatibility

[as old browsers like IE7 are slipping into a state of irrelevance](http://theie7countdown.com/) I want to focus on supporting the modern browsers well (IE9+, chrome, safari, opera and FF).

I have this example:

```
    div {
    height:130px;
    width: 130px;
    background-color: #F8A844;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

div:hover{
     transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
```

[css 3 property transform shown in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65kw9/1/)

css transform seems to work fine in FF 25 and IE 11. It does not work in chrome 31 though.

I stumbled across this. Now instead of stumbling / testing and figuring out every little problem like with this css transform property, I would like to automate this process. Is there a website / tool which would help me analyze the css and suggest solutions to me? Instead of googling every occurrence of irregularity

Btw the tiny nifty css 3 example from above would become something like this [crossbrowser compatible css3 transform fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65kw9/2/):

```
div {
    height:130px;
    width: 130px;
    background-color: #F8A844;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -ms-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

div:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
    transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
```

Comment: @Sirko that's like a glossary, isn't it? I am more looking for something which I can run over my CSS file, and then check support for IE9+ etc

Comment: Right. For some automated testing you would need to build a tool out of this data.

Answer (score 0):

http://cross-browser-validator.com/

This site has made an automated tool that you (we) need!
Seems like they only test a few modern browsers (IE9+) though.

Also, they have a 30-day trial, then you need to pay starting at $19.